# bootstrap form too large

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a form within an area of width col-sm-8. There are three columns in the form: label, text input and username check. Width of label is col-sm-2, Width of username check is col-sm-1 and the rest should be text input. My calculation is text input should have a width of 5 but the result is too ugly. I tried to manually set the width to col-sm-7 but still not long enough. If I set the width of text input to col-sm-8 then I saw scroll bars on the bottom of the web-page. My goal is to
1. set width of label to col-sm-2 to the left;
2. set width of username check to col-sm-1 to the right;
3. text input takes whole width in the middle.
How to achieve this please?
My old code is below:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" id="content" style="border-left: #dbe0e3 1px solid;">
  <form name="form_register" id="form_register" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="text-center">Enter your details below.</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" maxlength="40" required />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1"><span id="usernameCheck"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" maxlength="20" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

The result of my new code is better but I just wonder if there is more elegant way:
Change div of username from

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
```

to

```
<div class="col-sm-7" style="width:75%">
```

Comment: Let's start with this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdVJzw What are you trying to do here I can't understand from your original question

Answer (score 1):

this code help you

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="content" style="border-left: #dbe0e3 1px solid;">
  <form name="form_register" id="form_register" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="text-center">Enter your details below.</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" maxlength="40" required />
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1"><span id="usernameCheck">User Error Check</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password *</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" maxlength="20" />
          </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```